# Visual Studio code 'open in browser' extension failed

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have installed [Open in browser](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=techer.open-in-browser) visual studio extension. But when I try to open the browser by shortcut <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd>. It fails showing the following:

```
Running the contributed   
command:'extension.openInDefaultBrowser' failed.
```

Please help if there's any solution.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Go to settings --> Extensions --> Open in Browser and set a default browser. In my case I have set it to "chrome" (it can be "firefox" too), so it opens in chrome every time I use the extension.

[image]

Comment: You can accept this answer if it resolved your issue. Thank you.

Comment: did not resolve for me (codium, snap'd chromium on ubuntu 19.10), using 'firefox' lead to a noop

Answer (score 0):

i have no problem when i using windows, but since i use linux open in browser extension not work because default browser not set as well, and i try to set manual in VS Code setting and set the plugin open-in-browser by default to Firefox

its solving my problem i hope its work to you

Answer (score 0):

i've had the similar issue, but with no errors. vs code just refused to "open in browser". all i had to do is to change the default app for html documents. for that right click any html document -> open with -> choose another app -> choose ur browser and check the checkbox

Answer (score -1):

If the above solution didn't work install its previous version
Vote up If this Helped !!